# More Efficient Keras LSTM Input?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

When creating tensors for an LSTM in Keras, the time series input seems so inefficient. Is there another way to do it? For instance, before being converted to a tensor, a series might be:

- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] with the label [9]. The next would then be:
- [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] with the label [10].
- [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10] --> [11]

And so on for however many numbers are in my series. In this case, I only have 8 time steps per sample, but I'm still in essence creating 8x the amount of data I originally had before sending it to the LSTM - the vast majority of it being redundant. For series with 50 time steps, I'm creating around 50x the original data. That just seems so inefficient. When all the data is coming from just one long sequence, is there a more efficient way to load that data into an LSTM? Does tf.data provide any such functionality that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, but you can try to use `return_sequences=True` (this model will support `Conv1D` as well, but won't support `Flatten` or poolings).

And then you can use shifted outputs:

- inputs `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` with labels `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
- inputs `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]` with labels `[b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]`

Basically:

- `x_train = original_sequences[:,  :-1]`
- `y_train = original_sequences[:, 1:  ]`

The consequences are:

- Possible border effects (in the beginning of the sequences, the model will not be very good)
- Unlimited input steps (the model will rely on more than just 8 steps to do it's prediction) - Depending on the data, the results may be too dependent on a sequence longer than you initially wanted

  - This may or may not happen, it's worth trying
  - If this happens, it may or may not be a problem, it depends on your intentions with this model
- Cannot use `Bidirectional` because the results would be influenced by future values. (On the same line, convolutions should use `'causal'` padding, otherwise future values would also influence the result).